# ASP.NET Core custom defined User Roles implementation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, roles, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to define a custom way of **User Roles** since my DB's structure for the User table is the following structure:

---

[image: User Table structure]

***Role*** is a bool so if it's true the User is an Admin, else he's a normal User.

---

I know I need to declare the `add.UseAuthorization()` in **Startup.cs.** and I can add the Attribute `[Roles="Administrator"]` / `[Roles="User"]` inside the **Controller** but I am not sure how to define the role to be determined by my **Role** column from the User table.

I've been searching the internet, reading about **Policies** too but I don't think that's the right way to implement. Everything I've found online is about some sort **Identity** structure but doesn't make any sense on how to attach it to my **Role** column.

Hope, someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: This is really not the way to implement security. Please read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of implementing, based on my database without any modifications, is to use Claims and Cookies. I've managed doing this reading the following documents

[Link One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

[Link Two](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

I've encountered only one major issue which was solved by reading [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1318).

I'll also add the Login method and the **Startup.cs** rows, so others can see how to use it (if the docs aren't enough).

**Login** method from the **Controller**

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserModel userModel)
    {
        if (_iUserBus.LoginUser(userModel))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userModel.Email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _iUserBus.GetRole(userModel.Email)),
                };

            ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = false,
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, authProperties);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Email and/or Password wrong");

            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Users/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Users/Logout";
        });
```

Hope this is useful to anyone in need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to manipulate your DB, I would highly suggest using [IdentityFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity), it's a powerful framework which can integrate in your own database.

But to answer your question specifically, there's two steps missing:

- Pick an authentication scheme to login the user (e.g. Cookie-based, ...)
- Once the user logs in, save the designed **Role** in a ClaimsPrincipal object. This way the `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` declaration can pick this up.

Below you'll find a basic example using the default ASP.NET Core template in Visual Studio.

1. Add the Authentication middleware your `ConfigureServices` method, and configure it using a `AuthenticationScheme`. In this case I'm using Cookie authentication.

   ```
   //in ConfigureServices, add both middlewares
   services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddCookie();

   //in the Configure() method, enable these middlewares
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions());
   ```

Now you're ready for action. Let's say you have an Action method in which you want to authenticate the user. This is where you want to transform your Role so it can be recognised by `[Authorize]`

2. Get the value you need from your database. You'd end up with a `bool`. Convert it to a Role `Claim`, and add that to a `ClaimsIdentity`.

   ```
   bool roleFromDb = true;  //this comes from db

   //convert to Claim of "Role" type, and create a ClaimsIdentity with it
   var adminClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleFromDb ? "Administrator" : "User"); 
   var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { adminClaim }, 
                       CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

   //signs in the user and add the ClaimsIdentity which states that user is Admin
   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
           CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
           new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity));
   ```

With that done, you can mark other actionmethods using the `[Authorize]` attribute, e.g:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public IActionResult About() { ... }

[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult Contact() { ... }
```

Now, only a signed in user with the "Administrator" role can visit the Contact page.

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) resource for a more finetuned configuration of the middleware used.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is what I was looking for because I got confused a little about what I read previously. I also talked with my mentor today and he told me about the same thing with Cookie-based and Claims. Thanks!